# How can I rig an object to animate from two different orientations?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, skeletal-animation, rigging

As an example: Say you're animating a skateboard. The board has a nose and a tail. Normally, the nose points forward and the tail points backward. Now say you have two animations: idle and trick. The idle is animated with the nose pointing forward. The trick, however involves the board rotating 180°, ending with the nose pointing backward, functionally swapping the nose and tail. Now, if you were to blend the trick animation back into idle, the blend would rotate the board back around so the nose points forward, which would not be the intended behavior. The intended behavior would be for the animator to somehow know that the tail is now the forward facing orientation and animate as if the tail were the nose.

I'm competent but no expert with rigging/animation and I've been racking my brain trying to come up with either a way to cleverly rig the object to somehow work as intended or to be able to modify the animations procedurally in code or something, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

This seems like a problem that *must* come up somewhat frequently with game animation, but I haven't been able to find any specific resources.

I'm using Blender and Unity.

Edit: To be clear, I'm not talking about root motion or the animating object's position/rotation in the world, just the orientation of the bones being animated.

Comment: i think your getting wrong. in unity we make animation and parent it wit and ampty object. parent sets the position and orientations and child just plays the naimations. this is the way animations work in unity you dont need to change direction or orientation of animations

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. I'm not talking about moving or rotating the parent object in the world. I'm only talking about bone objects' position and rotation change due to the animation.

Comment: that's a good question, I don't know much about using animations in games, (I only know the basics) but i think it would be good to know how to do this.